# Convergence of filters

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. If $F$ is a filter on $X$, then $B:=\{G\subseteq X\mid G\in T\;\text{and}\; G\in F\}$ is a basis for a filter $F^\circ$ on $X$. Prove that for $x\in X$ the filter $F^\circ$ converges to $x$ if and only if $F$ converges to $x$.

It is relatively easy to see that $F^\circ\rightarrow x$ implies $F\rightarrow x$, but I don't get the other implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F \rightarrow x$, then this means that every neighbourhood of $x$ is in $F$.

Now let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $x$. Then there is some open set $O$ that contains $x$ and $O \subseteq N$ (definition of neighbourhood). Then $O$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$, so $O \in F$ (as $F \rightarrow x$), and so $O \in F^{\circ}$, as $O \in F \cap T$. But as these form a basis, $N \in F^{\circ}$ as well. As $N$ was arbitrary, $F^{\circ} \rightarrow x$.

Comment: Thanks, it is very clear now!